# Signing documents in java via smartcard without pkcs11

Tags: java, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have to make application to sign documents with smartcard in jdk7. I found that I have to use java provider to pkcs11 to get certificate and private key from smartcard, but... it does not exists in jdk 7 (i'm using windows 7 64bit and I found info that pkcs11 is not supported in this version). 
And my question - any ideas how to do it in different way?

Sorry for my poor english... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows platform and your smartcard comes with Microsoft CSP or Minidriver you can try to use it via sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI provider.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832846/digital-signature-sunmscapi-provider-ms-crypto-api) for more info.