# How to load digital certificates from Operate System using Java?

Tags: java, ssl

I've been working on a digital signature solution for a while, everything about is fine but now our customer wants to get a login by digital certificate solution.

He shows an example from another web portal he uses, when  digital certificate option is choosen on login page it executes a jnlp that lists all Windows's certificates installed.

I believe jnlp sends some "desktop" module that runs on client station background to retrieve the certificates list then send it back to the server.

I found some things about SunMSCAPI that does exactly what I need and tried to load it but I always get an exception

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");
```

or

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("SunMSCAPI");
```

the result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchProviderException: SunMSCAPI
at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:118)
```

I read something about SunMSCAPI works only on Java 6 or below and 32 bits OS/JRE.

I'm lost here..I mean, I can't predict what Java version users have on their station. Plus, today it is quite possible to be a x64 system. And of course it could be a Unix system instead of Windows.

What is the best approach to attack it fellows?

Comment: How about: KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT") rather than KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("SunMSCAPI")?

Comment: Thx for your reply! unfortunatelly I've got the same result                Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore Windows-ROOT implementation not found
 at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:101)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832846/digital-signature-sunmscapi-provider-ms-crypto-api