# SunMSCAPI not working when calling wcf

Tags: java, security, keystore, tls1.2, jce

I know there is many similar questions, but i could not find any help in any previous question. I am trying to communicate with a wcf service from a java client, i used the auto generated stubs created by netbeans to achieve that. the wcf service is protected with client certificate authentication using TLS(1.2). I cannot make it work to use the SunMSCAPI provider (meaning i want to use the windows user local store to use the certificate as a client. (if there is another way or library to make it possible to use windows certificate local stores please share with me).

This SSLContext is not working to call the web service:

```
IService servicePort = service.getWSHttpBindingIService();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(sslVersion);

**KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
keystore.load(null, null);**

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

kmf.init(keystore, null);

KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);

BindingProvider bindingProvider = ((BindingProvider) servicePort);

bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory",sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

The error i get is, when debugging i can see the keys and the certificates in the KeyManagers array correctly:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:310)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
```

the pfx is installed in user local store correctly, because i used it in c# and it worked many times.

in the java code above also, when i use pfx directly instead of SunMSCAPI provider, it works:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

ks.load(pfxStream, pfxPassword.toCharArray());

kmf.init(ks, pfxPassword.toCharArray());
```

I am using windows 10. any help would be appriciated.

I got the SunMSCAPi idea from the following link:
[Digital Signature SunMSCAPI provider & MS Crypto API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832846/digital-signature-sunmscapi-provider-ms-crypto-api)

Comment: Note that if the server is returning a 403 then the SSL connection has been stablished. Is client certificate optional? I suggest to debug the SSL connection to check if the Windows-MY keystore is being found correctly -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: Thanks pedrofb, yes I did so, and it looks like it is seeing the windows-my.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was that there is many certificates in my localstore and according to my research KeyManager selects the first Key found that meet the criteria, meaning that it will not necessarily pick my certificate among them. i solved this issue, by creating a decorator over X509KeyManager that chooses my desired certificate alias. got the idea from this QA:

[How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to SSLSocket before connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting)